# Do running times match with O(nlogn)?

Tags: java, performance

I have written a class(greedy strategy) that at first i used sort method which has O(nlogn)

> Collections.sort(array, new
>   SortingObjectsWithProbabilityField());

and then i used the insert method of  `binary search tree`  which takes  `O(h)`  and    `h here is the tree height.`

for different   `n` ,the running time will be :

```
n,running time
17,515428
33,783340
65,540572
129,1285080
257,2052216
513,4299709
```

which I think is not correct because for increasing n , the running time should almost increase.

This method will take the running time:

```
Exponent = -1;



for(int n = 2;n<1000;n+=Math.pow(2,exponent){

     for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    Element e = new Element(rand.nextInt(100) + 1, rand.nextInt(100) + 1, 0);
                    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                        if (e.getDigit() == randList.get(k).getDigit()) {
                            e.setDigit(e.getDigit() + 1);
                        }
                    }
                    randList.add(e);
                }
                double sum = 0.0;

                for (int i = 0; i < randList.size(); i++) {
                    sum += randList.get(i).getProbability();
                }
                for (Element i : randList) {
                    i.setProbability(i.getProbability() / sum);
                }
                //Get time.
                long t2 = System.nanoTime();
                GreedyVersion greedy = new GreedyVersion((ArrayList<Element>) randList);
                long t3 = System.nanoTime();
                timeForGreedy = timeForGreedy + t3 - t2;
            }
            System.out.println(n + "," + "," + timeForGreedy/3 );
            exponent++;
            }
```

thanks

Comment: the running time is incorrect??? or it matches with O(nlogn)?

Comment: I suggest you run each of your tests for at least 2 seconds. The JVM warms up as you execute code and your result will vary over time for short tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your data appears to roughly fit an order of nlogn, as we can see below. Notice that the curve is *almost* linear, as for large values of n, logn is pretty small. For example, for your largest value of n=513, logn is 9.003.

There are ways to achieve more accurate timings, which would likely make the curve fit the data points better. Such as taking a larger sample of random inputs (I'd advise at least 10, 100 if possible) and running multiple iterations per dataset (5 is an acceptable number) to smooth out the inaccuracies of the timer. You can use a single start/stop timer to time all iterations for the same n, and then divide by the number of runs, to get more accurate data points. Just be sure to first generate all data sets, store them all, and then run them all.

Good choice to sample n at powers of 2. You just might want to subtract 1 to make them exactly powers of 2, not that it makes any real impact.

[image]

For reference, here's the [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) script used to generate the plot:

```
set terminal png
set output 'graph.png'
set xrange [0:5000000]
set yrange [0:600]
f1(x) = a1*x*log(x)/log(2)
a1 = 1000
plot 'time.dat' title 'Actual runtimes', \
    a1*x*log(x)/log(2) title 'Fitted curve: O(nlogn)
fit f1(x) 'time.dat' via a1
```

Comment: also I have done what you said but it is like the running times above!!

Comment: @user There is strong evidence to suggest it is O(nlogn), if that is what you mean by "correct". So you should probably be content with that and accept it as indeed correct.

Comment: I thought that O(nlogn) will always increase but here is not ! and because of this ,I thought that these running times may be incorrect !!

Comment: @user Some algorithms are very dependant on the input data, which is why I suggested increasing the number of data sets used. There are also other potential causes, from using a low precision timer to hitting the sweet spot in cache lining. The reasons can get very technical.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that easy to relate asymptotic complexity to running times. When the sample is so small there are lots of things that will affect your timing.

To have more accurate timings you should run your algorithm K times per instance (e.g. K times with 17, K times with 33 and so forth) and take the average time as sample point (e.g. K=100)

That said it looks about right. You can plot nlog(n) vs your timings and you'll see that despite the different scales they are growing similarly. Still too little sample points to be sure...

Comment: @stavnir indeed, random input would be better!

Comment: In addition to running the algorithm multiple times per instance, I would also recommend running it with a few different sample data sets for each value of n.  Big O is a worst-case analysis and sometimes you just get lucky and it runs faster than that.  I recently fixed an O(n^6) algorithm that no one had noticed because the data happened to be ordered in such a way that it would take much less time than expected.